# StreamReader and StreamWriter with Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, streamreader, streamwriter

I need some guidance here.

I am reading a excel file using a StreamReader , then get the file to a **string** using the StreamReader.ReadToEnd(); method. Then I write the string to a different location on the file system using a StreamWriter.Write() method.

Then I re-read file from the location I wrote it earlier. However it seems I am reading some garbage values and I can't open the excel file from the new location...

Am I doing something wrong here to file to get corrupted ? Am I missing something to do with encoding here ?

Comment: Try using `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`, or, if all you want to do is copy a file, `System.IO.File.Copy`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel files are binary. `StreamReader` is a kind of `TextReader`, and `StreamWriter` is a kind of `TextWriter`.

**Binary** and **Text** - not the same thing.

Comment: I think you got those backwards TextReader is a type of StreamReader and TextWriter is a type of StreamWriter.

Comment: Nope. [`TextReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) is the base class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer , Now i change my methods to read the xls from a BinaryReader then get the contents to a byte array and then convert it to string and write it back to a different location using the BinraryWriter . However still I can't open the xls file using Excel. It complains that it's not an excel file . .. Does it has to with the byte order mark ?

Comment: Do not write it as a string. It is _not_ a string. It is a series of bytes. And what's wrong with using `File.Copy`?

Comment: The file is encrypted so I need to decrypt it first before writing it the new location . The decrypt method accepts a string . Before trying out the decryption part I need to get this to work by readying by a BinaryReader --- > Convert to String ----> BinaryWriter ---> BinaryReader to work.... Or Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Yes. Don't convert to a string! If your encryption mechanism requires a string, then it's the wrong mechanism for encrypting ***binary***!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what Excel format you are using, you will find it very painful to read/write directly.  Libraries such as NPOI make this much easier.

The version that reads/writes xlsx files is still in beta, but stable in my use.  If you need xlsx format files, download from their site, instead of via NuGet. [NPOI on GitHub](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi)